# on_click function assigned to Streamlit button runs before the click event

Tags: button, onclick, form-submit, streamlit, onsubmit

I’ve assigned an on_funtion to a button .Which is supposed to run a python file and start capturing the webcam. It should only be started when the button is clicked . But whenever i run the streamlit server the function runs and start capturing without a click event.
The same thing happens to a form I've made also which is leading to empty data written to google sheets.

Here is the code:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import streamlit as st
from activity_check import high_count
act_lev = ""
def start_capture():
    subprocess.run([f"{sys.executable}", "activity_check.py"])
def run_cap():
    st.button("Start Capturing",on_click=start_capture)
run_cap()
st.write(high_count)
```

The function should start only when i click, but its executing automatically

I thought a gif would help
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because i i've imported this variable

```
**from activity_check import high_count**
```

when i removed it. It started working as normal.
Now i've to figure out a way to get the value of that variable somehow.

Anyway case closed

Answer (score 1):

this is a way to solve it:

```
    import subprocess
    import sys
    import streamlit as st

    from activity_check import high_count
    act_lev = ""

    def start_capture():
        subprocess.run([f"{sys.executable}", "activity_check.py"])

    if st.button("Start Capturing"):
        st.write(start_capture())

    st.write(high_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your button conditional.

```py
import subprocess
import sys
import streamlit as st
from activity_check import high_count
act_lev = ""


def start_capture():
    subprocess.run([f"{sys.executable}", "activity_check.py"])


def run_cap():
    cap_button = st.button("Start Capturing") # Give button a variable name
    if cap_button: # Make button a condition.
        start_capture()
        st.text("Captured Successfully")
 
run_cap()
st.write(high_count)
```

Comment: That didn't work its still executing the start_capture() function whenever i run the script.

Comment: Ok then you can change the format of your code so you can try that to see if with fixes your problem, but without **on_clike**. I will edit my answer.

Comment: i tried removing the on_click function from the button , and execute when [if cap_button] is set. But still the same result. This happens to other forms also.

Comment: But then did you put `start_capture()` under the  **if statement**? because I edited my answer.

Comment: The reason is because i i've imported this variable 

    from activity_check import high_count

when i removed it. It started working as normal.
Now i've to figure out a way to get the value of that variable somehow.

Anyway case closed

Comment: Ah ok, good  to hear that its up and running now.